# Disabling proxies using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I disable the proxy setting in the browser for the reporting server using Javascript or jQuery ? because the reporting runs on static pages.

I am new to jQuery.

I am getting the read timeout error due to proxy settings.

Comment: You cannot access advanced browser or OS settings using JavaScript or jQuery. Period.

Comment: Hi praveen, Is there any other way to handle it ...?

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot control those settings to the client from the server. No is the answer.

Comment: Once SO allows you, please click on the Tick sign on the left of answer and accept it. Make sure you do for your previous questions too.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access advanced browser or OS settings using JavaScript or jQuery. Period.

And according to a comment by [Andrea Corbellini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913824/andrea-corbellini), if it were possible, it would be a great security vulnerability.

*This is not a comment, but an answer. I hope there's nothing much necessary for this answer.*

Comment: I'd add that, if it were possible, it would be a great security vulnerability.